# How can Dancer app process HUP signal to close/reopen logfile

Tags: dancer, logrotate, starman

I wrote a Dancer app, with the log config:

```
logger:       file
logger_format: <%T> %m
log_path:     '/usr/local/myapp/log'
log_file:     'myapp.log'
log:          debug
```

and start it with:

**plackup -E deployment -D -s Starman --workers=10 --port 8080 -a bin/app.pl**

rotate the log file with logrotate

```
/usr/local/myapp/log/myapp.log {
    daily
    rotate 10
    create 0660 root root
    compress
    missingok
    dateext
}
```

but the new logfile is zero.

I tried to add postrotate in logrotate conf to send **HUP** and process HUP sinal in `bin/app.pl` with

**Dancer::Logger::File::init;**

but nothing help.

Can anyone tell me how to rotate the dancer's logfile?

Answer (score 0):

One solution to let this happen is that `plackup` supports the `-R` switch to watch a folder, so you could add `-R <appdir>/run` and then change logrotate to:

```
postrotate
  touch <appdir>/run/last.run
```

As far as I can tell though what you want can't be done in this configuration. Starman explicitly handles sighup to restart the child processes. From Starman/Server.pm:

```
24 # Override Net::Server's HUP handling - just restart all the workers and that's about it
25 sub sig_hup {
26     my $self = shift;
27     $self->hup_children;
28 }
```

Perhaps you need an alternative logging solution such as using `Dancer::Logger::Syslog`

Or, if you must write to a file, maybe check for changes with `Linux::Inotify2`